# printf seems to be overwriting itself

Tags: c

So I'm trying to format this line to go

```
******************* Flight Reservation Request  **********************
 email name (M 1986/01/01)
```

but all it prints is

```
******************* Flight Reservation Request  **********************
 (M 1986/01/01)
```

The code that does this is

```
FILE * pFileCust; // stream Input for Customer Reservation data
void processCommandSwitches(int argc, char * argv[], char * * ppszCustomerFileName);
void processReservations();
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char * pszCustomerFileName = NULL;
    // Process the command switches
    processCommandSwitches(argc, argv, & pszCustomerFileName);
    // open the Customer Reservation stream data file
    if (pszCustomerFileName == NULL)
        exitError(ERR_MISSING_SWITCH, "-c");
    pFileCust = fopen(pszCustomerFileName, "r");
    if (pFileCust == NULL)
        exitError(ERR_CUSTOMER_RES_FILENAME, pszCustomerFileName);
    // process the Reservations
    processReservations();
    fclose(pFileCust);
    printf("\n"); // included so that you can put a breakpoint on this line
    return 0;
}
/****** you need to document and code this function *****/
void processReservations() {
    rewind(pFileCust);
    char gender[1];
    char dob[11];
    char emailAddress[53];
    char fullName[31];
    char address[31];
    char city[21];
    char state[31];
    char zip[61];
    fscanf(pFileCust, "%s %s %s %31[^\n]", gender, dob, emailAddress, fullName);
    printReservations(emailAddress, fullName, gender, dob, address, city, state, zip);
}
printReservations(char email[], char name[], char gender[], char dob[], char address[], char city[], char state[], char zip[]) {
    printf("******************* Flight Reservation Request  **********************\n");
    printf("%s %s (%s %s)\n", email, name, gender, dob);
}
```

**input file**

```
M 1986/01/01 petem@xyz.net Pete Moss
123 Boggy Lane,New Orleans,LA,70112
H100.15005 2      
H222.15005 2
H200.15010 2
H333.15010 2       
END 0
M 1957/02/02 pcorn@abc.netPopCorn______________________
456 Kernel,San Antonio,TX,78210
H222.15005 10
HXXX.XXXXX 10
H333.15010 5
END 0
F 1958/03/03 pennyl@xyz.net Penny Loafer
789 Walking St,Philadelphia,PA,19102
H444.15001 1
H333.15010 1
END 0
M 1979/04/04 hgilmore@xyz.net Adam Sandler
444 Golf View,Hollywood,CA,92274
H100.15005 3
END 0
F 1989/05/05 butter@xyz.net Melba Toast
222 Cracker Blvd,San Antonio,TX,78222 
H333.15010 2
H444.15015 2
END 0
```

Comment: regarding this parameter: `char * * ppszCustomerFileName`,  `* *` is not a valid operator.   The correct operator is `**`  I.E. no interior space

Comment: regarding this line: `processCommandSwitches(argc, argv, & pszCustomerFileName);`   the pszCustomerFileName is already a 'char **' so adding the '&' now means the called function will receive a char *** parameter.    do look up/google/ 'threestarprogrammer'

Answer (score 1):

Based on this suggestion by Retired Ninja:

> You may have an embedded \r in the string. This can happen if you're reading a file created on Windows on an OS that doesn't use \r\n as a line end.

I changed my code from:

```
fscanf(pFileCust, "%s %s %s %31[^\n]", gender, dob, emailAddress, fullName);
```

to this:

```
fscanf(pFileCust, "%s %s %s %31[^\r\n]", gender, dob, emailAddress, fullName);
```

This fixed the problem and my output looks normal now.

Comment: Please explain why this change was necessary; different OS perhaps?

Comment: @Evert according to the course information I read seems to be a mixture of Windows and Linux for those who choose to do it in VS. They just have the requirement that it must be runnable on Linux. Get the feeling that some of these files probably got shuttled between OSes

Comment: @MichaelPetch I guess I was being pedantic or educational. I could have added the explanation myself (I see you did), but wanted the OP to do that. Otherwise it becomes a copy-paste answer without explanation. Manual Gomez: you still may want to accept this answer as the correct/working one.

Comment: @Evert Oh I still left that up to Gomez to explain the environment if he is so inclined (in the answer). The only thing I did though is credit Ninja and to tie his comment to the answer.